# Python Flask set cookie for both example.com and www.example.com

Tags: python, cookies, flask

I'm trying to return a response that sets a cookie for example.com and www.example.com. I've only been able to set the cookie for the domain the request originates from. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ah! set_cookie() has a domain parameter.

```
response.set_cookie('name', 'value', domain='.example.com')
```

Problem solved.